# Faker fouling VRT how can I run VRT tests with same random data so a visual diff is not found

Tags: php, jenkins, faker

I use faker in many projects.  Recently I have been introduced to VRT (visual regression testing)  this process takes a snapshot of the site before a deploy and then one immediately after a deploy and alerts the user to any changes in layout.  I am the sole FED dev for a brand and need to be able to repeat the random results from faker for the second time the VRT process runs.  If I do not the VRT process is useless because I get back too many fails to test them all.

Does anyone know a way I can continue to use faker for ongoing dev but somehow capture the random seed for a render, keep it and re-run it for the second VRT test?  So all the text will display the same way the second time.  We use Jenkins.

Perhaps there is a way to call faker that will pass a specific random number so we can use jenkins to run a build that passes a unique the random number?  So we would have "yarn run VRT-compile" instead of "yarn run compile" and "yarn run VRT-compile" would pass in the same random number.  How would I do this?

So here is what we found out: As it turns out utilizing jenkins we were able to add the custom php file for handling the faker seed variable and add/remove it to the project before running yarn compile only for the builds we wanted it for. We submitted a PR to the faker plugin created by PatternLab our front end templating system for them to add this capability to the plugin natively but did not hear back yet.

Comment: I have found that you can add a random number to produce a consistent output: faker.seed(123);
 
var firstRandom = faker.random.number();
 
// Setting the seed again resets the sequence.
faker.seed(123);
 
var secondRandom = faker.random.number();
 
console.log(firstRandom === secondRandom);

Comment: I just don't know how to pass that into a yarn build

Comment: As it turns out utilizing jenkins we were able to add the custom php file for handling the faker seed variable and add/remove it to the project before running yarn compile only for the builds we wanted it for.  We submitted a PR to the faker plugin created by PatternLab our front end templating system for them to add this capability to the plugin natively but did not hear back yet.